# Trying to get the current time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, dynamics-al

```
const hours = now.getHours();
Console.log(hours);
```

These set of code is giving me...

> Uncaught ReferenceError: now is not
> Defined

Note: This is a JavaScript code

I try to use w3school as reference and Google to check the built-in function for time in JavaScript, still I it the same sa now.getHours(); but didn't run

Comment: how is `now` defined by your code?

Comment: `now` doesn't have any built in meaning. You'll need a line of code like `const now = new Date()`.

Comment: if you change  your `now` unsuspected variable by another non-existent one like `bigBen` you will get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

To add an answer here - what you have written implies that "now" is already declared and that it has a method .getHours() which would give you the hours. Date objects have that method, so it might be a good idea to define "now" as a constant, then use the Date object method getHours() to log the hours at the time you declared the date.

e.g.,

```
const now = new Date();
const hours = now.getHours();
console.log(hours);
```